# change css font with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change css font with javascript,

I changed font-size like below and it worked

```
$(".bp-item.bp-title.buyuk-baslik-yazi").css("font-size",
        +jsonVerisi.ayar[0].baslikFontSize + "px");
```

but when I try to change font-family by the same way,it doesn't work,is there anything that i'm missing ?

```
$(".bp-item.bp-title.buyuk-baslik-yazi").css("font-family",
            +jsonVerisi.ayar[0].baslikFontFamily);
```

Comment: What is the value of `jsonVerisi.ayar[0].baslikFontFamily`? I'd check that first.

Comment: `+` is to convert a string to number.. if the string is not a valid number then it makes it `NaN`.

Comment: i've already checked,it is selected by user and its value comes as expected like sans,sans-serif etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove "+" symbol from jsonVerisi.ayar[0].baslikFontFamily and try.

```
$(".bp-item.bp-title.buyuk-baslik-yazi").css("font-family",
            jsonVerisi.ayar[0].baslikFontFamily);
```

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your browser support specified font because it should work in that way.